# DD4T POC using Java

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, cme, dd4t

We are implementing DD4T for the first time in our project, for the same client requested us to do some POC, proof of concept (display a simple page driven by DD4T framework).  As per our technology stack we have to implement this using Java at content delivery side.

As mentioned we are new to DD4T implementation can anyone guide us, which all point we should consider before starting with implementation, also is there any article which can be useful before we start?

Answer (score 2):

The main point to start implementing a dd4t poc in java is 
https://code.google.com/p/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/wiki/31_Quickstart

There you may find the code, and some tips for the implementation.

And there is a lot of blog entries about dd4t in the Tridion community.